# QField: Draw line/polygon freehand using a digital pen on Android Tablet

Tags: qfield

I have a Samsung Tab Active (Android) with pen and would like to draw lines or polygons freehand. Not just tabbing and adding a new node. Is that possible or planned?

Comment: Hello, you can use freehand to draw your data. Freehand was introduced in version 1.8 https://github.com/opengisch/QField/releases/tag/v1.8.0

Comment: ah, thank you, I was probably a little too impatient... :-)